# How to use .Numberformat in VBA with variable string and integer value?

Tags: excel, vba, string, variables, number-formatting

Is there any way I can get a number format to look like this in the spreedsheet cell through VBA code?: EMBASAMENTO - ANDAMENTO GERAL: 50%. Nonetheless the "EMBASAMENTO" is a variable of the type string, "-ANDAMENTO GERAL:" is a permanent text, and "50%" is the value that is calculated and set to the cell in percentage format.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
   Nfil = 3
   Ntot = 5
   Model = "EMBASAMENTO"
   Piler = Nfil / Ntot
   Range("E7").Value = Piler
   Range("E7").NumberFormat = """ - ANDAMENTO GERAL: ""0%"
End Sub
```

Comment: I've included your requests, thanks i'm new in the forum...

Comment: I tested the `.NumberFormat` as it is in your code and it works as expected. Are you getting an error? Or getting the wrong percentage? Remember that something like 2.2 will format to 220%. You need to divide it by 100 if you expect it to be 2.2%.

Comment: See the Code I posted below in the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need quotes before the variable too, like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
  Nfil = 3
  Ntot = 5
  Model = "EMBASAMENTO"
  Piler = Nfil / Ntot
  Range("E7").Value = Piler
  Range("E7").NumberFormat = """" & Model & "- ANDAMENTO GERAL: ""0%"
End Sub
```

Not sure the `Worksheet_Change` event is the right place for this, but that's not part of your question.

Comment: That's it! Thanks very much man!

Answer (score 0):

The code I posted in the question is working. What I need and I am trying to do is something like this below, but it's not working:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
  Nfil = 3
  Ntot = 5
  Model = "EMBASAMENTO"
  Piler = Nfil / Ntot
  Range("E7").Value = Piler
  Range("E7").NumberFormat = Model & """ - ANDAMENTO GERAL: ""0%"
End Sub
```

The final result of this code should be EMBASAMENTO- ANDAMENTO GERAL: 60%

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).